# Ubuntu 14.04 Not Showing Existing partitions

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, mbr

I am having a problem while installing Ubuntu with windows 7 (Both are 64 BIT).

My windows 7 is already installed, when I try to install Ubuntu 14.04, it is not showing my partitions, instead it is showing entire 1TB HD.

I know this question is already asked [here](https://superuser.com/questions/744916/ubuntu-14-04-installer-doesnt-show-existing-partitions)

But when I tried `sudo fixparts /dev/sda1`

I am getting following output:

[image]

I am not able to get what to do ahead. I am new to Ubuntu, so can any one help me?

Comment: Can you post the output of `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda` and `sudo gdisk -l /dev/sda`

Comment: Your partition table is damaged. Please do as bain suggests so that we have a better idea of what's wrong.